# Json Parser Exception Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: c#

This code generates an exception of unexpected character. What is the problem with this code?
Error is: An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.DLL but was not handled in user code

> Additional information: Unexpected character encountered while parsing
>   value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.

```
HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "Application/JSON");
var page = http.GetStringAsync(searchUrl);
var o = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(page.ToString());
```

Comment: type of searchUrl is uri.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpClient.GetStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551745%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns a `Task<string>`.

You don't wait for it to complete, instead you call `.ToString()` on it, which is likely to either:

- Return the full name of the `Task<T>` type
- Return some internal string representation of the `Task<T>` type (*unlikely*)

As such, what you have is not the Json document, but the task string, which you then try to deserialize Json from.

Try:

```
string page = await http.GetStringAsync(searchUrl);
```

or:

```
string page = http.GetString(searchUrl).Result;
```