# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: �. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api, json.net

this opportunity Ii'd like to thank everyone who has an answer to this question, I'm trying to get a json from my web api service and I can't this is my code at the web api...

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<CompanyType>))]
    [Route("GetList")]
    [DeflateCompression]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
    {
        List<CompanyType> companyTypes = (List<CompanyType>)MemoryCacheManager.GetValue(@"CompanyTypes");
        if (companyTypes != null) return Ok(companyTypes);
        companyTypes = await _CompanyType.Queryable().ToListAsync();
        if (companyTypes == null) return Ok(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        MemoryCacheManager.Add(@"CompanyTypes", companyTypes);
        return Ok(companyTypes);
    }
```

and at the site of my client I got this

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string action, string authToken = null)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (!authToken.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(@"Bearer " + authToken);
            var result = await client.GetAsync(BuildActionUri(action));
            string json = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json); //This line fails because the characters in the value
            throw new ApiException(result.StatusCode, json);
        }
    }
```

As you can see there nothing than weird here it is a simple code that try to parse a json value to a Generic class but this fails bacause when i call my webapi Url it gives me this value

json =  ��VR�LQ�R2T�Q�2u�B*R�"E�e�)�@q�������̔Ԣb%��Ҝ�Z�>#�>#�>�̊B������J�r2�q�

I don't know why my webapi give me tha value, when I try to debug just my service it give me this value

```
<ArrayOfCompanyType xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ><CompanyType z:Id="i1" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><Id>1</Id><Type>Privada</Type><JobProviders i:nil="true" /></CompanyType><CompanyType z:Id="i2" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><Id>2</Id><Type>Mixta</Type><JobProviders i:nil="true" /></CompanyType><CompanyType z:Id="i3" xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"><Id>3</Id><Type>Publica</Type><JobProviders i:nil="true" /></CompanyType></ArrayOfCompanyType>
```

as you can see everything looks fine but the problem start when I try to parse to get this value from my client.

this is my class

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true, Name = @"CompanyType", )]
public class CompanyType : Entity
{

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }


    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Type { get; set; }


    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public virtual List<JobProvider> JobProviders { get; set; }
}
```

I tried it without de DataContracts and still the same error.

best regards!.

Comment: I think this is a problem in your JSON Return Type.  These links might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/24042770/2501044    http://stackoverflow.com/a/21651645/2501044

Comment: Do you mind in DeflateCompression Attribute? because I´m using this article to use gzip compression http://blog.developers.ba/asp-net-web-api-gzip-compression-actionfilter/. as you can see there is this line (actContext.Response.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json");) where it says that the response is json.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out, I was trying to use this sample http://blog.developers.ba/asp-net-web-api-gzip-compression-actionfilter/ but the thing was that the serializer wasn´t registered, so at my startup project I did this

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new ProtoBufFormatter());
```

And I changed my Actions deleting the attribute [DeflateCompression]

```
[ResponseType(typeof(List<CompanyType>))]
[Route("GetList")]
//[DeflateCompression]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
{
    Logic goes here....
}
```

And It's working now, but now I have another Issue and its when I try to make a call to my webapi action where I have to response an IHttpActionResult there is an exception of

> no serializer defined for type: System.Object